# Remote Device Internet Connectivity Status - Android

Tags: android

I am working on a Server-client mechanism in which my client is a mobile device running any version of android. I want to check through my server if the remote android client is connected to the internet and the internet is working on it. I know there is no straight forward approach in this kind of scenario.
Would making the android client ping my server after every 5 minutes would be the best solution ? Or there is any other more efficient way that I am not aware of.
Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Connectivity Manager as a broadcast that can give you the status of the connectivity.

So whenever you want to check from server about the connectivity of the internet, you can use that status value to know the internet connection status.

As mentioned in docs ([connectivity-monitoring](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)) -

The ConnectivityManager broadcasts the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` (`"android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"`) action whenever the connectivity details have changed. You can register a broadcast receiver in your manifest to listen for these changes and resume (or suspend) your background updates accordingly.

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.Yes , i know of this broadcast receiver method and i am using it too. But my problem is how will i access this connectivity status value of my mobile device from my server ??

Comment: It is not known that what is the purpose of checking this status from server rather then from client as we normally do (with the anomaly - Server serves and client reacts on what's served). The scenario you mentioned really need to continuously poll the server for the updated feedback.

Comment: Its a scenario in which the server will check with the client if its data pack is working or not. If its working, it will send an email, if it is not working, it will send an sms.

Comment: Ok so do this - Server says to client, hey Is your data pack working by sending some variable. When client receives that variable, it knows that server is asking for a connectivity check. So client responds with some response (usually a connectivity status) that, hey my data pack is working so please send me email or else if not working then please send me sms.